# content/div slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need my div to shift to and fro when clicked, like only one div should show on load and the other should not be visible and when clicked should come into view and vice versa , any kind of transition, i dont wish to use slick carousel, don't know where i went wrong cant figure out why even the inline block doesn't work.

```js
 function step(n) {
   
   if (n == 1) {
     $(".agever").animate({
       "left": "-300px"
     }, "slow");
   } else if (n == 2) {
     $(".contever").animate({
       "right": "300px"
     }, "slow");
   }
 }
```

```css
.light {
  background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
img#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
 body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.footer {
  float: left;
  background-color: #0f0f0e;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 125px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: .7;
  bottom: 0;
}
.agever {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(252, 251, 227, 0.1);
  width: 800px;
  height: 325px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 250px;
  top: 150px;
}
.agetitle {
  color: #a88d2e;
  color: rgb(168, 141, 46);
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 28.8px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.policy,
.policy a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #9b9b9b;
  color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-family (stack): Montserrat;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 28.8px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0px;
}
.yes a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  letter-spacing: 0.28px;
  word-spacing: 0px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0px;
}
.no a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 21px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  letter-spacing: 0.28px;
  word-spacing: 0px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0px;
}
.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button1 {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button5 {
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
}
.button5:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: white;
}
.contever {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(252, 251, 227, 0.1);
  width: 950px;
  height: 625px;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 250px;
  top: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 18px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.tandpcontent {
  color: #f6f5d8;
  font-family: Montserrat font-size: 16px text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  line-height: 19.8px
}
.tandptitle {
  color: #a88d2e;
  color: rgb(168, 141, 46);
  background-color: #000000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 28.8px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.close-icon {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 955px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-width: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%, white 56%, transparent 56%, transparent 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0%, transparent 46%, white 46%, white 56%, transparent 56%, transparent 100%);
  background-color: gray;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#tandpchange {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#containblockd {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#tandpmaster {
  display: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
agemaster {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="containblockd">

  <div id="agemaster">
    <div class="agever">
      <p class="agetitle">
        YOU MUST BE OF LEGAL DRINKING AGE IN THE COUNTRY IN WHICH YOU ARE ACCESSING THIS SITE
      </p>
      <p class="yes">
        <a href="main.html">
          <button class="button button5">YES I AM OF LEGAL DRINKING AGE</button>
        </a>
      </p>
      <p class="no">
        <a href="https://www.google.co.in/search?site=&source=hp&q=kingspirits.net&oq=kingspirits.net&gs_l=hp.3...518.518.0.1500.2.2.0.0.0.0.155.262.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..0.0.0.0.ZgyZZmdP464">
          <button class="button1 button5">NO,I AM NOT OF LEGAL DRINKING AGE</button>
        </a>
      </p>
      <p class="policy">
        By entering this site you agree to our <a title="Law" onclick=" step(1)" id="tandpchange">Terms & Privacy Policy.</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tandpmaster">
    <a href="#" onclick=" step(2)" class="close-icon"></a>
    <div class="contever">
      <p class="tandptitle">
        TERMS & PRIVACY POLICY
      </p>
      <p class="tandpcontent">
        some content.....
      </p>


    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Animate by itself doesn't show or hide elements. 
So you should add the hiding and showing logic in the complete function, as follows, by example (or using animation parameters in show and hide)

```
function step(n) {

   if (n == 1) {
      $(".agever").animate({
        "left": "-300px"
        }, "slow", function(){

               $(".agever").hide();
               $(".contever").show();
        });
  } else if (n == 2) {
    $(".contever").animate({
       "right": "300px"
        }, "slow",function(){
               $(".agever").show();
               $(".contever").hide();
       });
   }
 }
```

Moreover you should also handle the positions of your DIVs after they have been shown, hidden and shown again as the DIVs will return in the position reached after each animation.